# Need to run 'docker login' command inside a pod created in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

i am trying to lunch a new pod from  in side another pod using Kubernetes cluster, but when trying this following error message could seen in the ,

Failed to pull image "dhammikalks/node": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/dhammikalks/node:latest": failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/XXXXXXXXXX  9: 429 Too Many Requests - Server message: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit

from what i can find-out, i need to login to the docker registry in-order to avoid this, can someone explain how can i do this ?, currently docker commands are not available inside the pod.

Answer (score 1):

Easy option to overcome docker rating limiting problem is to have the image stored in private repo.  There are different articles to understand how docker rate limiting works.  For this you wouldn't require docker login commands inside the container.

Please use kubernetes secrets if required to supply login credentials of image repository.  Request to refer kubernetes [sample definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret) how to use "imagePullSecrets"